# How to implement Casle Windsor installer to install different modules for debug and release?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have any number of typical Castle Windsor installers like:

```
public class StrategyInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    #region IWindsorInstaller Members

    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<INavigationStrategy>()
                               .ImplementedBy<NavigationStrategy>()
                               .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

My question is how can I install a different (strategy for example) when I am in debug mode versus when I am in release mode?

(This would be for dependencies only available on the release environment)

Thanks

Comment: you can use `#if DEBUG` preprocessor directive or XML configuration with Release/Debug transformations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edned up using the following as per comment:

```
#if DEBUG
    container.Register(Component.For<INavigationStrategy>()
                           .ImplementedBy<NavigationStrategy>()
                           .LifestylePerWebRequest());
#else
    container.Register(Component.For<INavigationStrategy>()
                           .ImplementedBy<DebugNavigationStrategy>()
                           .LifestylePerWebRequest());        
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would not want the compiled code to be different between debug and release.  This can cause quite a bit of havoc when pushing out your release and that is the first time you are actually running the release binary.  That being said, your point is valid that you sometimes need a stubbed version of a class instantiated instead of the real version.

This is a bit more to set up, but I would suggest you make an assembly that contains the real implementation (such as connecting to the real database) and another assembly that contains the stubbed implementation (such as returning hard coded or configuration based database-like values).  Then have a config value that tells your application which assembly to load.  That way both the real and the stubbed implementation can be compiled in debug and release modes and you can swap out the assemblies in both environments.  This is also nice for testing out problems in production where you want to test something, but not actually have it hit the real implementation.